# Retreiving checked in baggage at transit if you have different airlines

Tags: visas, transit, malaysia, kul, nepali-citizens

If I have to travel A-B-C and I have different airlines from A-B and B-C, how can I get my checked in baggage at B? Do I need a visa of B just to get my checked in baggage?

I am Nepalese. I am flying from Manila to Kathmandu via Kuala Lumpur. I am taking Air Asia from Manila and Malindo Air from KL to kathmandu. So what will happen to my checked in baggage?

Comment: This depends on whether what A, B and C are and whether you have all in  one booking or separate tickets, your nationality and which airlines are involved, among others. Please specify.

Comment: I am Nepalese. I am flying from Manila to Kathmandu via Kuala Lumpur. I am taking Air Asia from Manila and Malindo Air from KL to kathmandu. So what will happen to my checked in baggage?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that. Also I take it that the two flights are on separate bookings?!?

Comment: Depends on airlines, airport and whether or not you have a visa for KL...?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get my checked in baggage at B (Kuala Lumpur)?

Your first flight from Manila to Kuala Lumpur is through Air Asia which lands at KLIA2. Your second flight from Kuala Lumpur to Kathmandu is through Malindo Air which departs from Main Klia (Kuala Lumpur International Airport)  which is a separate terminal and you definitely need to clear customs and immigration at KLIA2. Remember KLIA and KLIA2 are separate terminal and allow extra time in order to move from KLIA2 to KLIA main terminal.

Therefore, you need to check-in your luggage first at Manila airport and again at  KLIA  Malindo Air counter.

> Do I need a visa of B just to get my checked in baggage?

Yes, as a Nepalese National you need a visa if you are planning to enter Malaysia. However there is an exception to leave the transit area  when in transit between Main Terminal and KLIA2 if the  connecting flight is operated by Malaysia Airlines (MH) or  Air Asia (AK).

Source: [Visa And Passport Requirement](http://www.qatarairways.com/pk/en/visa-and-passport-requirements.page)

National Nepal (NP)             /Embarkation Philippines (PH)
Transit Malaysia (MY)           /Destination Nepal (NP)
ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW:

TWOV (Transit Without Visa):

Visa required, except for Nationals of Nepal holding confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit For details, click here time of 120 hours at Kuala Lumpur (KUL), if arriving in and departing from the same terminal. (SEE NOTE 51541)

NOTE 51541: **It is only permitted to leave the transit area  when in transit between Main Terminal and KLIA2 if the  connecting flight is operated by Malaysia Airlines (MH) or  Air Asia (AK)**. When leaving the airport transit area,
   passports must be valid for at least 6 months from date of
   arrival.

"As you have already mentioned that you are using Malindo Air, you will not be permitted to leave the transit area. **Therefore you need a Malaysian visa for this itinerary as a Nepalese citizen.**"

Answer (score 2):

Air Asia and Malindo Air do not have an interlining agreement, so its probable that you may have to go to the baggage hall in Kuala Lumpur, collect your baggage and recheck it.

The following advice is available on the KLIA airport website:

> Kindly proceed through the Arrival Immigration check-point, collect your luggage (if any) and clear through Customs before checking-in at the respective terminal for your connecting flight. Passengers are reminded to ensure that they have the necessary valid travel documents (passport, Visa, etc.) to clear through the Arrival Immigration check-point into Malaysia.

http://www.klia.com.my/?m=airport&c=transit_info&id=3

It looks like you will need to clear immigration and customs in order to check your baggage with Malindo Air, as I cannot find any information on an airside baggage drop facility.

Its always worth asking the Air Asia staff member when you check your baggage in in Manila, as they may be able to interline it anyway...

Answer (score -1):

Most of the times you dont have to worry about your Luggage. If you've booked it as one trip  (using collborating airlines) you're Luggage is automatically transfered as well. To be sure ask it at the check in desk at the airport. The usa the the excaption in this case. here you Always have to fetch your Luggage and check them in again.

Comment: I don't think those two airlines have a agreement that allows check-through of luggage.

Comment: Did you book it as 1 trip? or did you book seperated tickets? In the last case you have to fetch your Luggage and check-in again.  Just like if it are seperate trips.

Comment: @mts Indeed. `AK/MAY CHECK BAGGAGE TO AK  B7  OZ  9P` ... and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

I had a flight a few years ago from London to Sri Lanka via Mumbai.

At Mumbai I asked airport officials to help me transfer my bag for me because I didn't have a visa for India. This didn't seem to be a problem and they managed to do it without me having to leave the transfer area.

I'd suggest you contact the transfer airport to see if they are able to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: It's not possible in this case. There is no interline agreement between the carriers.